# pasar el valor de un select a otro select

Tags: javascript, c#, html, mvc

tengo dos vistas,  vista1= victimas y vista2 = denunciante que son iguales solo cambia el nombre y  el id de la persona ingresada   1 = victima y 3= denunciante.

en denunciante tengo un check que cuando se marca tendría que jalarme  los datos de la victima,

el escript que uso para pasar los datos de victima  a denunciante es:

```
function Victima(valor) {
    if (valor == 1) {

        $("#anonimo").attr("style", "display:none") // esto es para ocultar otro check
        document.datos.PRIMER_NOMBRE.value = document.getElementById("PRIMER_NOMBREV").value
        document.datos.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE.value = document.getElementById("SEGUNDO_NOMBREV").value
        document.datos.TERCER_NOMBRE.value = document.getElementById("TERCER_NOMBREV").value
        document.datos.PRIMER_APELLIDO.value = document.getElementById("PRIMER_APELLIDOV").value
        document.datos.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO.value = document.getElementById("SEGUNDO_APELLIDOV").value
        document.datos.APELLIDO_CASADA.value = document.getElementById("APELLIDO_CASADAV").value  
        document.datos.TELEFONO_CELULAR.value = document.getElementById("TELEFONO_CELULARV").value  
        document.datos.TELEFONO_CASA.value = document.getElementById("TELEFONO_CASAV").value  
        document.datos.TELEFONO_OTROS.value = document.getElementById("TELEFONO_OTROSV").value        


    } else {

        $("#anonimo").removeAttr("style", "display:none")
    }

}
```

me hace lo que necesito, PERO solo en los input  y tengo varios campos de   que no me jala los datos

mi select  de victima es :

```
<label>10. Departamento:<b style="color:red">*</b></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="DEPARTAMENTOV" name="DEPARTAMENTO" onchange="MunicipioDenunciante(this.value);" required>
                <option value="99">Ignorado</option>
                @foreach (var d in ValorDepto)
                {
                    if (d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO == DEPARTAMENTO)
                    {
                        <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO" selected id="DEPVALOR">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
```

y deseo reflejarlo en el select de denunica:

```
<label>10. Departamento:<b style="color:red">*</b></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="DEPARTAMENTOD" name="DEPARTAMENTO" onchange="MunicipioDenunciante(this.value);" required>
                <option value="99">Ignorado</option>
                @foreach (var d in ValorDepto)
                {
                    if (d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO == DEPARTAMENTO)
                    {
                        <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO" selected id="DEPVALOR">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
```

intento esto  sin exito:

```
  var cod = document.getElementById("DEPARTAMENTOV").value;
        document.datos.DEPARTAMENTO.val(cod);
```

Comment: Si alguna respuesta pudo resolver el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo tu problema, podrías probar lo siguiente:

Tienes un check en tu vista "Denunciante", quieres jalar los valores de "Victima" y que los valores en tu Select de victima se carguen igual en denunciante, solo debes hacer lo siguiente:

Tu Select en Victima:

```
<label>10. Departamento:<b style="color:red">*</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="DEPARTAMENTOV" name="DEPARTAMENTO" onchange="MunicipioDenunciante(this.value);" required>
            <option value="99">Ignorado</option>
            @foreach (var d in ValorDepto)
            {
                if (d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO == DEPARTAMENTO)
                {
                    <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO" selected id="DEPVALOR">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Quieres que se refleje en la vista Denunciante, que es una copia exacta, unicamente que diferencias los ´id´:

```
<label>10. Departamento:<b style="color:red">*</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="DEPARTAMENTOD" name="DEPARTAMENTO" onchange="MunicipioDenunciante(this.value);" required>
            <option value="99">Ignorado</option>
            @foreach (var d in ValorDepto)
            {
                if (d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO == DEPARTAMENTO)
                {
                    <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO" selected id="DEPVALOR">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@d.COD_DEPARTAMENTO">@d.NOMBRE</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Por lo que podemos hacer es obtener el valor de DEPARTAMENTOV --> Victima, y cargarlo en DEPARTAMENTOD por medio de tu evento javascript, el cual no lo estas compartiendo en el codigo, y creo que allí esta la magia del dinamisno que quieres mostrar, si entiendes como pasar los valores a un simple input solo te hace falta pasarlo a un Select y actualizarlo.

```
var cod = document.getElementById("MUNICIPIOV").value;//Recibe el ID en la vista victima
document.datos.DEPARTAMENTO.value = cod;          
var combo = document.getElementById("MUNICIPIOV");
var valor = combo .options[combo .selectedIndex].text;//obtiene la descripcion            
$(".muniDenunciante").append('<option value="' + cod + '" selected>' + valor + '</option>').trigger("chosen:updated");//Agrega el valor, que supongo se carga vacio, puedes agregar el atributo 'selected' para hacer la comparación, utiliza **trigger("chosen:updated")** para actualizar el Select
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudo a resolver mi problema ya jalo los datos correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

En definitiva lo que quieres hacer es un tipo de `Select en Cascada`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="teams" id="teams">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </body>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var countries = ['Chile', 'España', 'Inglaterra', 'Italia', 'Alemania', 'Holanda', 'Argentina'];
    var option = '';
    
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
       option += '<option value="'+ countries[i] + '">' + countries[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#country').append(option);
    
    var teams = {
        'Chile': ['Colo-Colo el Más Grande', 'La U', 'Católica'],
        'España': ['Real Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Atlético Madrid'],
        'Inglaterra': ['Manchester City', 'Chelsea', 'Manchester United'],
        'Italia': ['AC Milan', 'Juventus', 'Napoli'],
        'Alemania': ['Bayern Munich', 'Werder Bremen', 'Borussia Dortmund'],
        'Holanda': ['Ajax', 'PSV'],
        'Argentina': ['River Plate', 'Boca Juniors', 'Rosario Central']
    }
    
    var $teams = $('#teams');
    $('#country').change(function () {
        var country = $(this).val(), team = teams[country] || [];

        var html = $.map(team, function(t){
            return '<option value="' + t + '">' + t + '</option>'
        }).join('');
        $teams.html(html)
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Nos cuentas si te sirvió =)

Comment: Pues  eso ya lo tengo  lo que yo deseo es que    lo te tenga en el select de victima  me aparesca en el select de denunciante  con el siguiente script logro mostrar  en una alerta el codigo  peor no se como mostrarlo en el select de denunciante.    var cod = document.getElementById("DEPARTAMENTOV").value;
            alert(cod);

Comment: Para entender mejor.. lo que quieres es que en el segundo select te aparezco el texto concatenado? Por ejemplo si elijo victima 1 y denunciante 2, que aparezca en el segundo select "victima 1 - denunciante 2".. eso?

Comment: gracias  ya  lo solucione.